# Copy Postgres databases with indexes between instances

Tags: postgresql, index

How do you copy a single Postgres database between installations without using pg_dump and without regenerating indexes?

We have an application we deploy which uses Postgres 8.4.7 database in Linux. We have a rather large static data set (4GB) which is is indexed.

Using pg_dump we have to index the data once it is restored to the second Postgres instance. Indexing this data can take up to 80 minutes, so we would rather deploy the database with the index already generated.

From postgres documentation it appears that databases are contained in sub-directories under postgresql/8.4/main/base based on their OID.

My first attempt was to create an empty database in Postgres, shutdown the instance, then copy the data from the existing instance to the directory of the OID for the empty database. This failed as my indexes were not working. Preforming a vacuum gave me the following error:

```
WARNING:  PD_ALL_VISIBLE flag was incorrectly set in relation "pg_type" page 6
WARNING:  PD_ALL_VISIBLE flag was incorrectly set in relation "pg_depend" page 39
ERROR:  xlog flush request 0/8B199518 is not satisfied --- flushed only to 0/8AF81680
CONTEXT:  writing block 39 of relation base/17004/2608
```

Comment: Using the approach above I was able to query data, but with out the indexes my queries took more then 40 seconds.

Comment: Did you consider copying the entire instance and then dropping in the new cluster the databases you don't want?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to copy a complete PostgreSQL database *within its cluster*, the fastest method is to use it as `TEMPLATE` in a [`CREATE DATABASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createdatabase.html) statement. I quote the manual:

> By default, the new database will be created by cloning the standard
>   system database template1. A different template can be specified by
>   writing TEMPLATE name. In particular, by writing TEMPLATE template0,
>   you can create a virgin database containing only the standard objects
>   predefined by your version of PostgreSQL. This is useful if you wish
>   to avoid copying any installation-local objects that might have been
>   added to template1.

```
CREATE DATABASE db_copy TEMPLATE db_org;
```

This effectively copies underlying files around like you tried manually. Except that is sets everything up to work correctly.

You may want to [clean up](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-vacuum.html) your original *before* you do (depends):

```
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE;
```

Comment: The template database would have be created first... So, yes I would not have to reindex but I would still have to create the template database initially which would require generating the index.

Comment: The goal is to one time copy a database including indexes on a file level between stopped instances of the same version of PostgreSQL. This database is intended to be read only, it is not going to be updated or edited by any clients once deployed. If this process were remotely possible, it would require editing the postgres system database to update OIDs and other information pertinent to the database.

Comment: @MoeBe: To be clear, **any** database in the cluster can serve as template. Since you want to `copy a database` the original has to exist already. Of course, the cluster can't be in a stopped state, but has to be up and running.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :-) But my original question wasn't really specific to a cluster.

Comment: @MoeBe: You may want to clarify the question. "Instances" could be databases, clusters, installations, ...